# WebGUI for Virtualization?

Tags: linux, virtualization, web

Are there any virtualizations that can be accessed via a WebGUI too?

I mean the administration part is enough on a terminal, but we need a virtualization/webgui solution for "customers".

So that they could for ex.: reboot their guest machine or reach it when it's "frozen" [bsod/kernel panic] or maybe clone it, etc.

There is Xen with the xen-shell, but it's not good because it's only available via terminal.

Any solutions?

Comment: what should I choose? please vote for best :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.convirture.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

Convirture!

Answer (score 3):

vmware server is available via webinterface afair

Comment: For more info see the vSphere Web Access Administrator's Guide: http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere4/r40/vsp_40_web_access.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Xen and XVP have many tools for management that are free and open source.  If you're looking specifically for a web tool, try [XVP](http://www.xvpsource.org/).  XVP is a web-based GUI tool that leverages Java to provide all the access that could possibly be req

Answer (score 3):

Here is a web gui for VirtualBox: [phpvirtualbox](http://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [xen-admin](http://xen-admin.de/en/about-xen-admin) , it has the capabilities to give your users the ability to mange their VM.

And maybe [Proxmox](http://www.proxmox.com/products/proxmox-ve) is good too, but i don't have any experience with it.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of excellent web UIs are mentioned in other answers, however if you are managing VMs, I would recommend using [OpenStack](http://openstack.org). Just for UI, it'll be overkill but trust me requirements are always increasing.

OpenStack will provide you an API upon which you can build an interface easily both for customers and the administrators and modify to suit specific needs. It is being used and contributed to by several reputed providers including Rack Space, Citrix and NASA.

Answer (score 2):

There is many various GUI, cli and WEB tools for managing your virtualization platform http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Management_Tools . This isn't only for KVM, some of tools supports XEN, openvz

Answer (score 1):

XENui: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qib1lbUeblM [sorry in Hungarian]
but it's not released to public yet.